# How to process HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have made an HTML form. It is a sort of a research form and generate scores based on the values entered through some formulae. After I have done with calculating scores, I want to send the scores via an email. Should I use PHP or JavaScript to do that? 
thank you

Comment: It's not possible to use client side javascript for sending emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP provides a convenient way to send email with the mail() function.

> Syntax
>
> mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)

Example :

```
<?php
    $to      = aa@bbb.com;
    $subject = 'results';
    $message = 'message ';
    $headers = 'From: your_email@xxx.com';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You can learn this concept **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)**

You can see examples **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Post your form to a PHP script and you can read the form fields using the $_POST variable. Make sure your form has name="xxx" fields. These will be your $_POST['xxx'] array index names.

Comment: Please expand on your answer as this isn't sufficient as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculations in Javascript,in browser, in clients side.
But sending emails.... you do this via PHP, on the server side.

An example of a PHP script sending the email, as follows
See how I get form field values using `$_POST` array they come in?
You can build a looong email using lots of variables, just add them to the message.

```
<?php

$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Your results';
$message = 'Hello, this is your score email.<br>';
$message.= 'Your result is: '.$_POST['score'];
$headers = 'From: your@email.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```